# WPF Binding to a viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, private, setter

I'm simply binding a WPF DataGridTextColumn with a binding to my grid rows.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
```

I've bound to my row view models.  The Name property has a PRIVATE setter.

```
public string Name 
{
    get { return _name; }
    private set { _name = value; }
}
```

Shouldn't the datagrid prevent me from accessing the private setter?  The grid allows me to access it.

I swear it never used to, unless I'm forgetting something?

Answer (score 0):

If that's the case, just set the binding to one way, and problem solved ...